# Should I double data or power lines for UART device

Tags: power, uart, data

I just have a quick question.
I'm connecting PN532 NFC reader with RPi, for this I am using around 30m of UTP cable from my front door to rack with RPi, preliminary test showed the device is able to communicate over 30m of cable in UART mode - with data and power each via single pair.

Now I have one pair in UTP cable free, should I use it to double-up the power (3.3V, GND) lines or data (TX,RX) lines which use 3.3V signal? This will drop that pair's effective resistance and increase their current capability. What makes more sense to make it more reliable? Max current is around 100mA for the NFC reader. I measured the voltage at the end while max power consumption at 3.1V (datasheet specifies 2.7V minimum for the PN532 chip)

I don't mean to double the lines for redundancy in case of one pair failing, but to minimize the voltage drop over the long distance of the cable, I am just not sure if giving it the double of the wire gauge is better for data or power (either using one whole pair for GND, second for 3.3V power, or one wire of each pair for RX and one of each pair for TX for data - to keep the benefits of twisted pair).

Thank you

Comment: If anything, use one free pair for GND and the other free pair for V+

Comment: Welcome to the site. You're talking about using a second set of wires to provide redundancy: if the another wire(s) fails, you can use these instead. This is to improve reliability. But just using the wires anyway, with no reliability problem to solve, can actually decrease reliability, as you've added more points of failure by unwanted shorts. So the question actually is on you: what in your equipment is the most unreliable and most likely to fail? Only you can answer that, by editing and greatly improving your question (don't add question detail in comments). Thanks and again, welcome.

Comment: @schnedan thank you, so you are saying doubling it for the power is more beneficial than doubling the data lines? - of course doing it the way I now specified in the question based on your suggestion

Comment: @TonyM - I have added more details to the question - thank you

Comment: Thanks. Please can you add the data bitrate and the power supply voltage and current consumption to the question, too.

Comment: @InToSSH doubling the data lines (splitting the signal energy) might cause reflections and make it worse. for Data lines it would be better to switch from single ended signals like RS232 to a system based on differential signals.

Comment: Please also add the UART signalling voltage to the question. Your linked data doesn't say but I've got the feeling it's an (LV)TTL interface (3.3 V or 5 V) rather than RS232C. That won't give reliable communications over 30 m over time. But the acceptable level of comms reliability is determined by the equipment requirements and your application, so that's back to you, too - please add that to the question. (Please don't put 'edit' or credit anyone, you can just expand the question :-) )

Comment: If power efficiency is a concern, consider the power loss at 3.3V/1A (or actual current) across that length of cable.  Then calculate the same loss at a higher voltage (say 24v/0.1375A).  If the latter is >20% efficient, then a 90% efficient boost regulator at the source, followed by a 90% buck regulator at the load, will reduce losses in the cable and thus improve overall power delivery efficiency.

Comment: @TonyM When I was at TI Germany 20years ago the guys archived 50m RS232 in the laboratory with their best chip (If I remember correct they also used reduced levels like 5V) - so I guess 30m are possible when done right, but's not "recommended" :-)

Comment: Thank you for your responses and suggestions.. I added even more info to the question. To sum up, measured max current at the end (PN532 module) is around 100mA, voltage dropped to 3.1V, since datasheet specifies 2.7V min for the chip, it should be ok as far as power goes. Now the question is if doubling the signal wires would make it better or worse. Signal voltage is 3.3V for UART on Raspberry Pi. Unfortunatelly using anything other than UART, I2C or SPI would make it too complicated and I would probably rather put the RPi directly to the box with PN532.

Comment: Hopefully you did not use a pair which put Tx twisted with Rx.  What you should do is run each in a pair twisted with ground.   You could then run power, or better yet higher voltage power and regulate at the far end.  And better still use differential line driver/receiver chips for Tx and Rx.

Comment: Extra pair of wires, over 30 m?  I would definitely be considering RS-485, as it is meant for this very situation.

Comment: @schnedan, (with no disrespect to your guys' good achievement) it comes down to that engineering maxim: designing something that works is relatively easy, it's designing something that never doesn't work. Something that you can make as many as you want for as many years as you want and the design is reliable and working after all those years. Your guys might have used a proper line driver at lower voltage. But an (LV)TTL logic gate driving all that cable at a decent speed is just asking for trouble, over time, over many units. OP's probably making one but should use good engineering practice.

Comment: @TonyM - This is why I stated they just tested in the lab. It was never suggested to be used. Just a benchmark for the internal book of records - nothing more. if the datasheet states 15m you of course should not exceed it.

Comment: @ChrisStratton thank you, yes for the test out of convenience I used only one twisted pair for both TX and RX. For the actual connection I will do it the way you suggested and as normal UTP is supposed to be wired for LAN networking (orange: TX, orange stripe: GND, G: RX, GS: GND) and whole separate pair for +3.3V power. I know there are many other better and proper ways how to do it. I could power it with 12/24V and use buck converter at the end, I could use level shifters (I guess) or even RS-485 or others.. I just wanted to know without other changes, how to efficiently use those pairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there are no more comments here, to sum it up:

With this setup there should be one pair for each TX and RX, where in one pair there are TX and GND wires and in second pair there are RX and GND wires, but this set up will not work reliably over such a long distance.

To make this connection work properly RS-485 or RS-422 should be used,  which use differential signals.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the power for the data lines source is from the power line, it would be wiser to decrease the drop to the NFC reader that will also decrease the voltage drop in the GND and power line for the rest of the circuit.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I am not sure if I understand correctly, are you saying that it would better to minimize the voltage drop on the NFC reader so the NFC reader has enough power to power the data lines back to the RPi? And yes NFC reader uses 3.3V provided from the RPi over power lines (in one cable) to drive it's data lines.

Comment: @InToSSH Yes, it's better to minimize the power drop to the NFC reader. The voltage drop here will be the same as the drop over the transmit wire if the wire is of the same size. So if you minimize the drop to the NFC reader you also minimize the drop on the transmit wire where the power comes from. If now the NFC transmit on the same voltage level as the power source has. Mean while you will also get less impedance in the line to the NFC reader. Which you will not get if you just improve the the voltage drop in the power line.

Comment: thanks, that makes sense, if I get around 0.2V drop on the NFC side, now the transmit voltage from the NFC back to RPI will start on 3.1V and by the time it reaches the RPi, it might drop another 0.2V to 2.9V, which might not be enough. Yea, as stated in the comments above I will either use buck convertor and run higher voltage through the wires or actually put RPi directly to the box with the NFC reader.